# Add startup program to Windows Server 2008 r2

Tags: boot, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm not actually sure if this is possible but I have three programs I want to run when the server starts.  The thing is I would like it if they ran without anyone actually logging in.  Right now I RDP into the server, start the three programs, then disconnect without logging out so they keep running.

Comment: Depends if the programs actually support being started as a service.

Comment: Its not detailed enough to be an answer.  I don't make a habit of posting single sentence answers if I cannot expand on the information and/or provide alternate solutions.

Comment: That does answer my question though, they aren't services. You can expand on it a little if you want to say make sure it's a service as they are the only thing you can start that way.